# MailCore2 not Fetch Sent Items from Yahoo/OutLook mail in iOS

Tags: ios, email, imap, mailcore2

I am using the below method to fetch INBOX emails;

```
[self.imapSession fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder:inboxFolder requestKind:requestKind numbers:[MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:fetchRange]];
```

and get all mails successfully but when I try to fetch Sent Mails it shows the following error in the log

> 2015-04-21 18:13:23.961 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 1 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:23.962 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 2 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:23.962 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 3 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.189 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 4 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.190 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 5 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.191 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 6 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.191 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 7 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.192 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 8 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.193 TestMailCore[10138:212892] Progress: 9 of 10
>       2015-04-21 18:13:24.194 TestMailCore[10138:212892] fetched all messages. Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=19 "An error occured while
>   fetching messages in the requested folder." UserInfo=0x7fee934ee710
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=An error occured while fetching messages in
>   the requested folder.}

Comment: Could you show connection logs?

Comment: sure 
`2015-04-22 12:56:27.306 TestMailCore[3112:68079] checking account`

`2015-04-22 12:56:32.956 TestMailCore[3112:68079] finished checking account`

Comment: Use connectionLogger on MCOIMAPSession.

Comment: Hey...Could you please help me.? I am trying to retrieve hotmail/outlook mails. I have got access token by Auth2.0. Now which configuration are you using? like port number , host name, connection type? Please help

Comment: Hi, sure i help you give me some detail for how you are trying to fetch the inbox. i don't think so that there is any need of Auth 2.0. Simple username, password with the hostname and you can login successfully and can fetch its inbox mails.